# .map is not a function - react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm trying to map over an API response but it gives me "TypeError: response.map is not a function".

I think it might be due to the map method getting a string instead of an array. but when I `console.log` it gives me an array so I can't really see where the error comes from.

Or maybe I'm accessing the API response array in a wrong way.

I've read tons of documentation and threads but still can't get what am I doing wrong.

Thanks in advance

```js
{status: {…}, outputs: Array(1), rawData: {…}}
   outputs: Array(1)
    0:
     created_at:"2018-08-24T19:58:44.351091715Z"
     data:
      concepts:Array(20)
       0:{id: "ai_69gDDQgl", name: "hamburger", value: 0.9955255, app_id: "main"}
       1:{id: "ai_QLn2rxmZ", name: "lettuce", value: 0.9920815, app_id: "main"}
```

```
const IngredientsList = ({ response }) => {
    const items = response.map((item) => 
<ul>{item}</ul>)
    return (  
        <div>
            <p>{items}</p>
        </div> 
    )
}
```

Comment: `response` is not an array, so it doesn't have `.map()`.

Comment: Can I turn it into an array? Or am I not calling correctly?

Comment: To expand on the above comment, `map` is a method on the `prototype` of an `Array` object in Javascript. (eg. `Array.prototype.map`) See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map for more information

Comment: It's an object that contains status, outputs, and rawData.  What are you trying to map?  I'm not sure how your map function would work on any of the available arrays.

Comment: I presume you want to do the map on response.outputs?

Comment: @Devon, this is an app where you put a food picture URL, sends a request to the API, which responds the ingredients. In the case attached it was a burger ("hamburger", "lettuce")... I want to render the name and the value to the screen.

Comment: Yes @ChrisCousins

Comment: @Francisco well, `response.outputs[0].data.concepts` is where those items are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would render the concepts array with name and value in a list?

```
const IngredientsList = ({ response }) => {
    if (!response || !response.outputs) {
        return null;
    }
    const items = response.outputs[0].data.concepts.map((item) => <li>name: {item.name}, value: {item.value}</li>);
    return (  
        <div>
            <ul>{items}</ul>
        </div> 
    )
}
```

Comment: It gives me "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined". I've tried this before and it's strange since I can console.log what I've written at the Question. Thanks for your help btw

Comment: Please put it in a codepen or show the exact error (line too).

Comment: I've copied your code and it gave me: "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined" on line > 6 |     const items = response.outputs[0].data.concepts.map((item) =>

Comment: I see, that is not an issue with the code in the answer, it is because your render is most likely happening before your API call has returned. Simply add a check into your render so that it can return null when response is empty, and/or has no outputs array.

Comment: I see, maybe build this in a class with constructor and then use componentWillUpdate before the render?

Comment: With react, it is entirely possible that the async data you refer to in your rendering is not ready yet/does not yet exist. It is therefore good practice to have the render able to cope with that, for instance you can simply return null in that case. I will edit the answer.

Comment: Brilliant, it worked. I wasn't thinking about the time the app needed to render before the API response. Definitely a lesson for the future. Thanks a lot @Chris.